# Firefox in macosx is not displaying xml tree

Tags: xml, firefox, ubuntu, macos

I have currently changed to Mac from Ubuntu and for some reason viewing xml files in Firefox differ between the two. In Ubuntu Firefox(3.5) I get a XML tree but in Mac OS(10.6) Firefox(3.6) i get plain text. To se the xml tree i need to check the source. It is the same xml file. 
Could someone please explain why and how to turn it on in Firefox for Mac.
(thought it could be that Javascript was disabled, but is enabled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haha, found the answer to my question. If firebug is activated the xml tree isn't displayed.